# c++ - const member func, that can be called upon lvalue instances only, using a ref-qualifier

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++17, ref-qualifier

I'm trying to enforce a const 'getter' method of a class to be called upon **only lvalue** instances of the class, via a ref-qualifier and for some reason getting an unexpected result (I'm compiling with *clang 6.0.1* with *C++ 17* support, via *c++1z* flag, on *Windows*):

The declaration `bool getVal() const &;` allows the method to be called **on rvalue references also**.

The declaration `bool getVal() &;`
**doesn't allow the method to be called on rvalue references BUT, as I understand - the function isn't a const method no more**, which is problematic, design-wise, for a 'getter' method.

What's the right way to get both characteristics for a method?

Comment: Const lvalue references may bind to rvalues

Comment: @M.M you're absolutely right, I want sure what's the right way to avoid it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `bool getVal() const &;`, but add a deleted overload for rvalues:

```
bool getVal() const && = delete;
```

Comment: @golosovsky You're welcome! Consider pressing the green checkmark to the left on the answer to mark your question as solved.